# VBA : Changing Windows 7 Default Printer temporarily

Tags: c#, vba, printing, default, administrator

is there any possibility to change the windows default printer for one "job" only? Does it work without having adminstrative permissions under Windows XP / Vista / 7?

what i want to do:

- Default printer is Canon ABC
- want to print via Epson XYZ
- after printing want to having back my default printer Canon ABC again.

Best would be if it will work without administrative permissions and without "messageboxes" or UI Dialogs.

Should be used under VBA or (grudgingly) under C# / .NET

Comment: what have you tried to accomplish this task? Will VBA only allow printing to the default printer?

Comment: Which VBA? There can be a difference between versions and products.

Comment: .. eg MS Access 2003 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223133(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: MS Access 2003 based Application (VBA6 i think), it should use a defined printer (like EPSON XYZ) to do only one job (1 print job) and then switch back to the default printer that was before.

Comment: **You absolutely do not need to change the *default* printer in order to print to a particular printer. Nor *should* you do so.** Just instruct your application to print to a particular printer, and leave the default printer alone. You'll need to be more specific about which version of VBA that you're using in order for someone to write the code for you.

Comment: thank you cody, its vba code inside a ms access 2003 based mdb file (later compiled as mde) it should print a barcode (TLP Zebra) to it via the TLP Zebra Printer and then switch back to the normal printer for DIN-A4 Sized Paper.

Comment: Why are you making "i think statements" you need to avoid words like that.  What exactly is the application written in?  You don't need to change the default printer, detect the printers that can be used, and select the correct one.

Comment: @Ramhound: Now now, let's not beat up on someone who is admitting lack of knowledge. Besides, he has provided adequate information in his statement to know what the platform is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can print to any printer installed on the computer. You don't need to change the default printer. I don't know exactly if it's the same in VBA, but it works in C#.

**Edit**:

Due to your comment I added a little sample, hoping to lead you on the way:

```
public void DoPrint()
{
    var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var printDocument = new PrintDocument
            {
                DefaultPageSettings = { PrinterSettings = printDialog.PrinterSettings }
            };
        printDocument.PrintPage += OnPrintPage;
    }
}

private void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello");
}
```

This will print "Hello" to the printer you've selected in the dialog.

Comment: do you have some snippet or helpful page about printing a job with a different printer? what parameters do i use and what namespaces do i need? (if its possible it should only use .NET 2.0 cause of compatibility with Win2000, WinXP without SP)

Comment: @DanielAlexanderWeigl: I've added a little sample to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From Access help:
The following example makes the first printer in the Printers collection the default printer for the system, and then reports its name, driver information, and port information.

```
  Dim prtDefault As Printer
  dim strOldDefault as string
  strOldDefault = Application.printer

  Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(0)

  Set prtDefault = Application.Printer

  With prtDefault
      MsgBox "Device name: " & .DeviceName & vbCr _
          & "Driver name: " & .DriverName & vbCr _
          & "Port: " & .Port
  End With
```

*Edit*: You can easily save the default printer before changing it, and set it back again after printing. Also, since changing the default printer is a slow process, I would recommend that you check what is the default printer before changing it, in order to avoid un-necessary changes.

---

To save/restore:

```
Dim strOldPrinter As String
'save old printer'
strOldPrinter = Application.Printer.DeviceName
'....do stuff'
'restore old Printer'
Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(strOldPrinter)
```

Comment: you're right that would be hell on earth if it will override the default printer :o how about : "Print with EPSON ABC report "mybusinessreport" " would it be like Application.Printers("Epson ABC")?

Answer (score -1):

Being that you did not specify what your "job" actually is, I will supply a simpler answer here.

As an alternative to the programmatic methods, if you are specifically trying to print a particular **report** via a certain printer, there is built-in functionality in MS Access to accomplish this.

Simply select the Print Preview view of your report, and then select:

Page Setup -> Page tab -> Use Specific Printer -> Then browse and choose!

This wound up working for my needs, so hopefully it will help you as well.

Comment: Can someone clarify why this post received a downvote? A solution that does not necessitate code is still a solution, and the OP did not specify what these print jobs entailed.

Comment: i don't know why and who have given you a downvote. The Solution is okay, if you let someone see the toolbars given in Access. The Main question years ago was if it is possible to save the current default printer, change the default printer to another device, print on this new device and reset to the default printer afterwards. Without any needs to do something manually.